# Compare RGB colors in a pixel and change its original color to the closest one

Tags: c#, colors, pixel, rgb

I need help for my assignment. Basically, this is what I want to do:

- Load an image to a `PictureBox`
- Calculate the difference between 255 (the maximum value) and the R value in each pixel, and the difference between 255  and G value, and also for B value
- From the calculation above, the least absolute value will indicate that the pixel's color is closer to that color (ex: (255-R value) has the smallest absolute value, so the pixel is closer to that color)
- Change the pixel color to the closer color (in example above, it means change it to Red)
- Display the result in the output picturebox

As the result, I will obtain the image with those three primary colors.

I have written the code like this:

```
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(InputPictureBox.Image);
        byte R, G, B;
        Color pixelColor;
        for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
            {
                pixelColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                R = (byte) Math.Abs(pixelColor.R - 255);
                G = (byte) Math.Abs(pixelColor.G - 255);
                B = (byte) Math.Abs(pixelColor.B - 255);

                if (R < G && R < B)
                {
                    pixelColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (G < R && G < B)
                {
                    pixelColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (B < R && B < G)
                {
                    pixelColor = Color.Blue;
                }
            }
        }
  OutputPictureBox.Image = img;
```

The problem is that the color image then turn to be inverted. So, what is wrong in my code? I assume that the `if` statements don't work, but I don't know why. Am I wrong?

One more question related to my code above, can it actually work by simply calculating the gap of R/G/B value like that OR it absolutely has to be done by using euclidean distance?

If you don't mind please show me how to fix this or maybe how the code should be written. I ever read a quite similar question, but the given answer still didn't give me a clue.

Comment: Accessing bitmap data using managed APIs is generally far too slow. Consider using unsafe function pointers to read and manipulate the bitmap data directly. Here's a good article that I like: http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Comment: I would suggest replacing 'Math.Abs(pixelColor.R - 255)' with '255 - pixelColor.R' as you know this will always be positive anyway.

Comment: @ByteBlast Ah, yes, thak you for your comment. I had read some references about unsafe mode, then lockbits, but for now I want to solve how to fix the code above

Comment: @JoeF I had tried both 'Math.Abs(pixelColor.R - 255)' and '255 - pixelColor.R', yet both of them still make the colors become inverted. what's wrong? :(

Comment: @feanifarida If I understand your problem correctly, you want to make the colors match their closest primary color? Let's say that you have Pink (255, 192, 203) - should that become Red? Because its Red component is the highest - did I get that correct?

Comment: Can you show us how you are setting the color back onto the bitmap?

Comment: What do you mean by "inverted"? Where is the code where you assign back the color to an image?

Comment: @Jesse yes, that's what I mean :)

Comment: @Abhinav I've edited the code in my question and put in the last row

Comment: @LightStriker inverted --> just like when you invert the color of an image

Comment: But you're not inputing a new color anywhere... You aren't doing anything with "pixelColor". I see no "SetPixel" anywhere.

Comment: @LightStriker Oh yes, you're right. I re-read my code and 'SetPixel' is not there. Thank you :)

Comment: @feanifarida I'm glad it helped at least some. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code actually works, although there is a bit of overthinking put into it.

Try this:

> ***The code has been moved to the* Update *section at the bottom of the post***

Result:

[image: Result]

---

**I've removed** the overthinking part.

- There's no reason (at least from reading your question) why you need to invert the color component values;

  1. Simply doing `R = pixelColor.R` is enough;
  2. And through this you *don't* have to think of it as "which has the **least** amount of 
     red", but rather, "**if** it has the *most* amount of red, it's **red**!"
- As [LightStriker pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095030/compare-rgb-colors-in-a-pixel-and-change-its-original-color-to-the-closest-one/16095664#comment22980907_16095030): You are missing (it is nowhere in your code) the code to set new value back into the image;

  1. This is accomplished using `img.SetPixel(x, y, pixelColor)`.
- I've added an `else` clause to match pixels where **no single color component** is greater than both others.

  1. For example, Yellow (255, 255, 0) would not be matched by your rules;
  2. Using the version in this answer, it gets replaced by a `Black` pixel.

---

**Update:** per the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095030/compare-rgb-colors-in-a-pixel-and-change-its-original-color-to-the-closest-one/16095664?noredirect=1#comment23245481_16095664) asking for additional clarification. Here's how you would add more conditional statements:

```
// NEW (start) --------------------------------------------------
Color[] randomizedColors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue };
Random randomizer = new Random();
// NEW (end) --------------------------------------------------

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(InputPictureBox.Image);
byte R, G, B;
Color pixelColor;

// NEW (start) --------------------------------------------------
Func<int, Color> ColorRandomizer = (numberOfColors) =>
{
    if (numberOfColors > randomizedColors.Length)
    {
        numberOfColors = randomizedColors.Length;
    }
    return randomizedColors[randomizer.Next(numberOfColors)];
};
// NEW (end) --------------------------------------------------

for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
    {
        pixelColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);
        R = pixelColor.R;
        G = pixelColor.G;
        B = pixelColor.B;

        if (R > G && R > B)
        {
            pixelColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (G > R && G > B)
        {
            pixelColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (B > R && B > G)
        {
            pixelColor = Color.Blue;
        }
// NEW (start) --------------------------------------------------
        else if (pixelColor == Color.Yellow)
        {
            // 2 = Red or Green
            pixelColor = ColorRandomizer(2);
        }
        else if (pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(152, 152, 152))
        {
            // 3 = Red, Green, or Blue
            pixelColor = ColorRandomizer(3);
        }
        /* else if (pixelColor = Some_Other_Color)
        {
            // 3 = Red, Green, or Blue
            pixelColor = ColorRandomizer(3);
        } */
// NEW (end) --------------------------------------------------
        else
        {
            pixelColor = Color.Black;
        }
        img.SetPixel(x, y, pixelColor);
    }
}

OutputPictureBox.Image = img;
```

With this updated code, add all colors that should be picked randomly to the `randomizedColors` array. Use the lambda function, `ColorRandomizer`, to assist in choosing a color randomly; keep in mind that this function will randomly pick between **the first element** and the one specified.

Comment: Sorry for the late additional question : if I don't want to use black (for example, I have that Yellow color (255, 255, 0) and I want the program to choose between Red and Green), can I use the similar method as when I generate random number? Is there any way to choose between two methods (ex: between pixelColor = Color.Red and pixelColor = Color.Green) or even three methods?

Comment: @feanifarida Absolutely! It all depends on their priority. If you want them to take precedence, then add them **before** the existing condition (`if` statements). On the other hand, if you want them to be considered *after*, then simply add them to the bottom.

Comment: I've read some references related to random method. One of them gives an example similar to this form: state = Random.value < .5 ? State.Left : State.Right; But when I tried to put Random.value < .5 ? Color.Red : Color Green to choose randomly between two colors, it doesn't work

Comment: @feanifarida If I understand you correctly...when you encounter `Yellow`, you want to *randomly* choose `Red` or `Green` - is that what you're wanting?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. As what you've been explained in the code, for some condition like (255, 255, 0) or (152, 152, 152), of course I cannot define whether it is Red/Green/Blue if I use the previous rules, that's why you suggest to use black. But how if when it is (255, 255, 0) I want the program to choose between Red and Green randomly, and for this one (152, 152, 152) it chooses Red/Green/Blue randomly?

Comment: @feanifarida I've updated the answer. Please take a look to see if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is really really helpful, since before I only adapt the concept to generate such random numbers or randomly picking item from a list, and I was stuck with that. Once again, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Following is inverting all the colors.

```
R = (byte) Math.Abs(pixelColor.R - 255);
G = (byte) Math.Abs(pixelColor.G - 255);
B = (byte) Math.Abs(pixelColor.B - 255);
```

You can use:

```
R = (byte) pixelColor.R;
G = (byte) pixelColor.G;
B = (byte) pixelColor.B;
```

Comment: If you read the if statements you will see that this is wrong.